# Avoid need for `.\` when running executables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I thought I could add `$env:Path = $env:Path + ';.'` to the end of my Powershell 7 `$PROFILE` to enable running current-directory executables, but sadly this adds only the first directory from which I attempt to run a executable from. Switching to other directories and trying to run local commands seems instead to run commands from the first directory. Any idea why?  Is there a way to do this more generally?

Answer (score 4):

The behavior - which **affects only [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** up to at least v7.3.3, **not also *Windows PowerShell*** - is indeed curious and suggests that PowerShell *caches* the value of `$env:PATH` and *at that time* resolves `.` to whatever the current directory happens to be.

However, this **looks like a bug** - see [GitHub issue #15795](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15795) - and would be even less helpful if you tried to make `.` a part of the *persistent* `$env:PATH` definition, as the logic then applies to PowerShell's *startup* directory.

Given that **the need for `.\` to run executables located in the *current* directory is a *security-minded* feature** - it prevents accidental invocation of a different, potentially malicious executable than intended - **I suggest *not* looking for workarounds.**

Instead, you can **rely on *tab-completion***:

For instance, if there's a `foo` executable or PowerShell script in the current directory, typing `foo`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will complete to `.\foo.ps1`, for instance.

Note:

- On *Windows*, this always works smoothly by default, due to `PSReadLine`'s [`EditMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption#-editmode) option defaulting to `Windows`: the current-directory file is always tab-completed first, and if there are additional possible matches you can cycle through them by repeatedly pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- On *Unix*-like platforms, `EditMode` defaults to `Emacs`,  in which case typing an *ambiguous* name prefix - e.g., if `foo.ps1` exists in the current directory and there's also `foo.exe` in `$env:PATH` and you type `fo`<kbd>Tab</kbd> - initially just beeps to alert you to the ambiguity, requiring *another* <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress to then show a *non-interactive list* of possible completions, requiring you to type *additional characters until the prefix is unambiguous* and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> *again*.
  This is obviously cumbersome; there are two solutions:

  - If you don't mind switching to edit mode `Windows`, add the following to your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file:

    ```bash
    Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Windows
    ```
  - Alternatively, if you don't mind or even prefer that an interactive *menu* of completions is automatically shown in case of ambiguity, with the first match completing in-line right away (which would be the current-directory match), add the following to `$PROFILE`:

    ```bash
    Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Tab MenuComplete
    ```

    - Note that you may choose to do this on Windows too.

Comment: Great answer, but I disagree with "I suggest not looking for workarounds".  It is nothing but hassle.  I never save executable files that I'm not willing to run.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, well, even if you're not concerned about _maliciously_ placed executables, the instant feedback that tab-completion provides with respect to whether you'll end up executing a directory-local executable (whose tab-completed form will start with ``.\``) or one via `$env:PATH` can be helpful. That, combined with the fact that tab-completion only requires you to type a _prefix_ of the executable's name, makes it a net benefit to me.